# Passing data between intents

Tags: android, sqlite, android-intent

Lectori salutem,

I'd like to implement a search in my application, my main data stucture, a ListOf(custom class) is in my main activity. Which is a json-ed object with over 2500 objects. The json file gets loaded/parsed on the startup of my application, this takes about 30 seconds. So passing the data in a .putextra is really not an option. The search dialog would take 30 seconds to even start searching, not to mention you'd have twice the memory usage.

So question is, what are my options here? Is there a way of passing the search query to my mail intent, and handle it there, so I can address the existing data structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you would be best off using a SQLite database.  You can even distribute a pre-populated database with your application to minimize load time.

You can get started here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db

Comment: Your pre populated idea was in the back of my head the whole time, and last couple of days I've succesfully implemented it! :) Cutting my loading time to 0. I could remove the splash screen entirely, and no need to parse the json any more.

One question thou; I've got the DB helper object in my main intent/activity, I need to display a item from the database in an other intent. Whats the best way to do this?, I mean I could connect to the database all over again, but then I would end up having the DbHelper object in two places witch ofcourse is a programming death sin :) Thanks again! :)

Comment: You should create a new instance of your DbHelper object for each Activity.  Due to the lifecycle of your components, where they can get killed and later recreated, trying to share in-memory objects is not ideal.

Answer (score 1):

Why not try to keep the information in a singleton object? Or in your App class for example? Any of these should give you access to the object anywhere in the app.

Comment: Sounds good, for I'm still quite new, could you help me with a simple exaple? Or a link perhaps? Thanks!

Comment: And how are these handled during a orientation/configuration change?

Comment: The downside to this is that the singleton may not always remain in memory.  Android may kill processes to reclaim resources, and restart them later.  You would have to check to see if the singleton needs to be repopulated.

Comment: here you can see the singleton pattern: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern
It's the same. You just make a class which will keep your model.
Elevine is correct, the object can be lost in extreme cases. Same is for the activity itself - if it is in the background for too long, the system might kill it and then try to recover it (with its intent params). In that case you should be able to reload the content again.

Answer (score 0):

You should check if the data being copied into new object, or the reference of it being past. I'm pretty sure only the reference will be sent, and you don't have to wait for the object copied into new one. Therefore, stick with the putExtra, if you don't wan't to create static reference, who is the evil demon that summons memory leaks :)

Comment: I've ended up passing the search string to my main activity, and handle it there...